Jenkins failing to update existing EC2 worker node configuration
I have the EC2 plugin installed and configured on Jenkins. Workers are being successfully provisioned and connected to the controller.
Now the problem is that when trying to update properties of an already existing node / worker, the following exception is thrown:
Jul 08, 2024 2:52:01 PM WARNING hudson.init.impl.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler handleException
Caught unhandled exception with ID 678a7c22-540c-40e7-aedc-9135749eb190
org.kohsuke.stapler.NoStaplerConstructorException: There's no @DataBoundConstructor on any constructor of class java.lang.Boolean
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.ClassDescriptor.loadConstructorParamNames(ClassDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.instantiate(RequestImpl.java:871)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:775)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to instantiate class java.lang.Boolean from {"metadataEndpointEnabled":true,"metadataTokensRequired":false,"metadataHopsLimit":"1"}
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:778)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:558)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.instantiate(RequestImpl.java:884)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to convert the metadataSupported parameter of the constructor public hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2OndemandSlave(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,java.lang.String,hudson.model.Node$Mode,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.util.List,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.util.List,java.lang.String,int,hudson.plugins.ec2.AMITypeData,hudson.plugins.ec2.ConnectionStrategy,int,hudson.plugins.ec2.Tenancy,java.lang.Boolean,java.lang.Boolean,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Boolean) throws hudson.model.Descriptor$FormException,java.io.IOException
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.instantiate(RequestImpl.java:886)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:775)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to instantiate class hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2OndemandSlave from {"name":"EC2 (dev-us-east2-jenkins-aws-cloud) - jenkins worker on aws (i-0b225062fb969d7a7)","spotInstanceRequestId":"","cloudName":"dev-us-east2-jenkins-aws-cloud","templateDescription":"jenkins worker on aws","instanceId":"i-0b225062fb969d7a7","ec2Type":"On Demand","":["5 min 36 sec","0"],"publicDNS":"","privateDNS":"10.208.74.206","nodeDescription":"","numExecutors":"3","labelString":"active-worker","mode":"NORMAL","initScript":"# TODO: Enable either in AMI or here for prod\n# curl --tlsv1.2 --silent --show-error --header 'x-connect-key: 3f1292317af1667d1b5b8f38bb6b716540b5ca5a' https://kickstart.jumpcloud.com/Kickstart | sudo bash","remoteFS":"/tmp","remoteAdmin":"root","stopOnTerminate":false,"idleTerminationMinutes":"2","tags":[{"name":"jenkins_server_url","value":"http://10.208.107.214:8080/"},{"name":"tk:infra:dtap","value":"dev"},{"name":"Name","value":"dev-us-east-2-jobsdata-pipeline-jenkins-worker"},{"name":"jenkins_slave_type","value":"demand_jenkins worker on aws"},{"name":"tk:app","value":"jobsdata-pipeline-jenkins-master"}],"usePrivateDnsName":false,"tenancy":"Default","amiType":{"rootCommandPrefix":"","slaveCommandPrefix":"","slaveCommandSuffix":"","sshPort":"22","bootDelay":"","stapler-class":"hudson.plugins.ec2.UnixData","$class":"hudson.plugins.ec2.UnixData"},"maxTotalUses":"-1","nodeProperties":{"stapler-class-bag":"true"},"metadataSupported":{"metadataEndpointEnabled":true,"metadataTokensRequired":false,"metadataHopsLimit":"1"},"Submit":"","Jenkins-Crumb":"813391eec0bc041fe0adac859af159e5d321c2e4a5973a3b11eced8cd694a63d"}
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:778)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:558)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:553)
    at hudson.model.Descriptor.bindJSON(Descriptor.java:625)
    at hudson.model.Descriptor.newInstance(Descriptor.java:595)
Caused: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to instantiate class hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2OndemandSlave from {"name":"EC2 (dev-us-east2-jenkins-aws-cloud) - jenkins worker on aws (i-0b225062fb969d7a7)","spotInstanceRequestId":"","cloudName":"dev-us-east2-jenkins-aws-cloud","templateDescription":"jenkins worker on aws","instanceId":"i-0b225062fb969d7a7","ec2Type":"On Demand","":["5 min 36 sec","0"],"publicDNS":"","privateDNS":"10.208.74.206","nodeDescription":"","numExecutors":"3","labelString":"active-worker","mode":"NORMAL","initScript":"# TODO: Enable either in AMI or here for prod\n# curl --tlsv1.2 --silent --show-error --header 'x-connect-key: 3f1292317af1667d1b5b8f38bb6b716540b5ca5a' https://kickstart.jumpcloud.com/Kickstart | sudo bash","remoteFS":"/tmp","remoteAdmin":"root","stopOnTerminate":false,"idleTerminationMinutes":"2","tags":[{"name":"jenkins_server_url","value":"http://10.208.107.214:8080/"},{"name":"tk:infra:dtap","value":"dev"},{"name":"Name","value":"dev-us-east-2-jobsdata-pipeline-jenkins-worker"},{"name":"jenkins_slave_type","value":"demand_jenkins worker on aws"},{"name":"tk:app","value":"jobsdata-pipeline-jenkins-master"}],"usePrivateDnsName":false,"tenancy":"Default","amiType":{"rootCommandPrefix":"","slaveCommandPrefix":"","slaveCommandSuffix":"","sshPort":"22","bootDelay":"","stapler-class":"hudson.plugins.ec2.UnixData","$class":"hudson.plugins.ec2.UnixData"},"maxTotalUses":"-1","nodeProperties":{"stapler-class-bag":"true"},"metadataSupported":{"metadataEndpointEnabled":true,"metadataTokensRequired":false,"metadataHopsLimit":"1"},"Submit":"","Jenkins-Crumb":"813391eec0bc041fe0adac859af159e5d321c2e4a5973a3b11eced8cd694a63d"}
    at hudson.model.Descriptor.newInstance(Descriptor.java:598)
    at hudson.model.Node.reconfigure(Node.java:587)
    at hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2AbstractSlave.reconfigure(EC2AbstractSlave.java:508)
    at hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2OndemandSlave.reconfigure(EC2OndemandSlave.java:143)
    at hudson.model.Computer.doConfigSubmit(Computer.java:1531)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:732)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:397)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:409)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:207)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.SelectionInterceptedFunction$Adapter.invoke(SelectionInterceptedFunction.java:36)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.verb.HttpVerbInterceptor.invoke(HttpVerbInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.SelectionInterceptedFunction.bindAndInvoke(SelectionInterceptedFunction.java:26)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:140)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:558)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:59)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:770)
Caused: javax.servlet.ServletException
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:818)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:900)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$9.dispatch(MetaClass.java:475)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:770)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:900)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$2.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:224)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:59)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:770)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:900)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:698)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:248)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1665)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:163)
    at jenkins.metrics.impl.MetricsFilter.doFilter(MetricsFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:160)
    at jenkins.util.HttpServletFilter$1.doFilter(HttpServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:160)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at jenkins.ErrorAttributeFilter.doFilter(ErrorAttributeFilter.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:94)
    at jenkins.security.AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.java:52)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:54)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:101)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:97)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:63)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:111)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at jenkins.security.SuspiciousRequestFilter.doFilter(SuspiciousRequestFilter.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:569)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1580)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1306)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$RequestDispatchable.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:1598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.runTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.consumeTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.tryProduce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.run(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:969)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:1194)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1149)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

Jenkins version is: Jenkins 2.452.1
And EC2 plugin's version is: Amazon EC2 plugin Version 1688.v8c07e01d657f
I reckon this is a bug somewhere in the EC2 plugin / Jenkins code; but any idea on how to work around it would be appreciated.
